# How to set focus and insert caret in an empty text field in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, cs3

stage.focus = textField;

textField.setSelection(0,0);

is not working for me.

Comment: stupid question: is it selectable? :D

Comment: yes, it is default selectable.

Answer (score 1):

If the caret is not showing in your text field after using stage.focus = textField;

Simply try publishing your movie instead of testing it with the CTRL+Enter command.

It didn't work for me until I published it.

-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is "textField"  the child of a library movieclip? If so, you have to access it through the parent.

```
stage.focus = someMovieStageName.textField
```